# The usage of "Per se"

Tags: meaning, phrases, word-usage, meaning-in-context, british-english

Is the usage of the phrase "Per se" correct in this sentence?

Sometimes, religion, though not be enaugh per se, may lead to violence.

Answer (score 4):

Not really, although the problem is with your overall sentence construction more than the use. "Per se" means "of or in itself", so is really used for reflexive emphasis, e.g.

"Religion, while not necessarily advocating violence *per se*, can be a significant contributory factor."

as in

"Religion does not specifically call for violent behaviour, but can contribute via its teachings to a violent mindset or world view".

Ref: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/per-se?s=t